# Hidden features of Scala

Tags: scala, hidden-features

What are the hidden features of Scala that every Scala developer should be aware of?

One hidden feature per answer, please.

Comment: Heh, this question is as useful for it's links to the other hidden features posts as for the question itself. Cheers!

Comment: @mettadore just look at the _related_  links on the right side.

Comment: @JohnMetta: Or use the [tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hidden-features).

Answer (score 85):

Okay, I had to add one more.  Every `Regex` object in Scala has an extractor (see answer from oxbox_lakes above) that gives you access to the match groups.  So you can do something like:

```
// Regex to split a date in the format Y/M/D.
val regex = "(\\d+)/(\\d+)/(\\d+)".r
val regex(year, month, day) = "2010/1/13"
```

The second line looks confusing if you're not used to using pattern matching and extractors.  Whenever you define a `val` or `var`, what comes after the keyword is not simply an identifier but rather a pattern.  That's why this works:

```
val (a, b, c) = (1, 3.14159, "Hello, world")
```

The right hand expression creates a `Tuple3[Int, Double, String]` which can match the pattern `(a, b, c)`.

Most of the time your patterns use extractors that are members of singleton objects.  For example, if you write a pattern like

```
Some(value)
```

then you're implicitly calling the extractor `Some.unapply`.

But you can also use class instances in patterns, and that is what's happening here.  The val regex is an instance of `Regex`, and when you use it in a pattern, you're implicitly calling `regex.unapplySeq` (`unapply` versus `unapplySeq` is beyond the scope of this answer), which extracts the match groups into a `Seq[String]`, the elements of which are assigned in order to the variables year, month, and day.

Comment: Thx for posting this! FYI it's mentioned in the chapter "Extracting with regular expressions" in the book "Programming in Scala" on page 503 in the first edition and on page 611 in the second edition.

Answer (score 51):

*Structural* type definitions - i.e. a type described by what methods it supports. For example:

```
object Closer {
    def using(closeable: { def close(): Unit }, f: => Unit) {
      try { 
        f
      } finally { closeable.close }
    }
}
```

Notice that the **type** of the parameter `closeable` is not defined other than it has a `close` method

Comment: Structural types aren't even mentioned in "Programming in Scala". They're a bit slower than other techniques for passing types though since they use reflection to call the right methods. (Hopefully they'll come up with a way to speed that up.)

Comment: And there is also possible to make alias for them, what works like externally assigned interface (very slow one):

type Closeable = { def close(): Unit }

Answer (score 45):

### [Type-Constructor Polymorphism](http://lambda-the-ultimate.org/node/2579) (a.k.a. higher-kinded types)

Without this feature you can, for example, express the idea of mapping a function over a list to return another list, or mapping a function over a tree to return another tree. But you can't express this idea *generally* without higher kinds.

With higher kinds, you can capture the idea of *any type* that's parameterised with another type. A type constructor that takes one parameter is said to be of kind `(*->*)`. For example, `List`. A type constructor that returns another type constructor is said to be of kind `(*->*->*)`. For example, `Function1`. But in Scala, we have *higher* kinds, so we can have type constructors that are parameterised with other type constructors. So they're of kinds like `((*->*)->*)`.

For example:

```
trait Functor[F[_]] {
  def fmap[A, B](f: A => B, fa: F[A]): F[B]
}
```

Now, if you have a `Functor[List]`, you can map over lists. If you have a `Functor[Tree]`, you can map over trees. But more importantly, if you have `Functor[A]` *for any A of kind `(*->*)`*, you can map a function over `A`.

Answer (score 39):

[Extractors](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/112) which allow you to replace messy `if-elseif-else` style code with patterns. I know that these are not exactly *hidden* but I've been using Scala for a few months without really understanding the power of them. For (a long) example I can replace:

```
val code: String = ...
val ps: ProductService = ...
var p: Product = null
if (code.endsWith("=")) {
  p = ps.findCash(code.substring(0, 3)) //e.g. USD=, GBP= etc
}
else if (code.endsWith(".FWD")) {
  //e.g. GBP20090625.FWD
  p = ps.findForward(code.substring(0,3), code.substring(3, 9))
}
else {
  p = ps.lookupProductByRic(code)
}
```

With this, which is **much** clearer in my opinion

```
implicit val ps: ProductService = ...
val p = code match {
  case SyntheticCodes.Cash(c) => c
  case SyntheticCodes.Forward(f) => f
  case _ => ps.lookupProductByRic(code)
}
```

I have to do a bit of legwork in the background...

```
object SyntheticCodes {
  // Synthetic Code for a CashProduct
  object Cash extends (CashProduct => String) {
    def apply(p: CashProduct) = p.currency.name + "="

    //EXTRACTOR
    def unapply(s: String)(implicit ps: ProductService): Option[CashProduct] = {
      if (s.endsWith("=") 
        Some(ps.findCash(s.substring(0,3))) 
      else None
    }
  }
  //Synthetic Code for a ForwardProduct
  object Forward extends (ForwardProduct => String) {
    def apply(p: ForwardProduct) = p.currency.name + p.date.toString + ".FWD"

    //EXTRACTOR
    def unapply(s: String)(implicit ps: ProductService): Option[ForwardProduct] = {
      if (s.endsWith(".FWD") 
        Some(ps.findForward(s.substring(0,3), s.substring(3, 9)) 
      else None
    }
  }
```

But the legwork is worth it for the fact that it separates a piece of business logic into a sensible place. I can implement my `Product.getCode` methods as follows..

```
class CashProduct {
  def getCode = SyntheticCodes.Cash(this)
}

class ForwardProduct {
  def getCode = SyntheticCodes.Forward(this)     
}
```

Comment: isn't this like a switch? maybe this could be refactored more.

Comment: Patterns are like turbo-charged switches: much more powerful and clear

Comment: Nice, but I don't like that you have to use implicit because its scope reaches further than the match { }. You could also just add a method to ProductService that looks up a Product by code. You would wrap your refactored snippet in a method anyway to be able to use it everywhere.

Answer (score 35):

[Manifests](http://scala-blogs.org/2008/10/manifests-reified-types.html) which are a sort of way at getting the type information at runtime, as if Scala had reified types.

Comment: I think it's preferable to explain the answer _in_ the answer rather than referring to a link. By the way, hi agai oxbow! :-)

Comment: This is a truly hidden feature... not even in the API docs. Very useful though.

Answer (score 35):

In scala 2.8 you can have tail-recursive methods by using the package scala.util.control.TailCalls (in fact it's trampolining).

An example:

```
def u(n:Int):TailRec[Int] = {
  if (n==0) done(1)
  else tailcall(v(n/2))
}
def v(n:Int):TailRec[Int] = {
  if (n==0) done(5)
  else tailcall(u(n-1))
}
val l=for(n<-0 to 5) yield (n,u(n).result,v(n).result)
println(l)
```

Answer (score 35):

Case classes automatically mixin the Product trait, providing untyped, indexed access to the fields without any reflection:

```
case class Person(name: String, age: Int)

val p = Person("Aaron", 28)
val name = p.productElement(0) // name = "Aaron": Any
val age = p.productElement(1) // age = 28: Any
val fields = p.productIterator.toList // fields = List[Any]("Aaron", 28)
```

This feature also provides a simplified way to alter the output of the `toString` method:

```
case class Person(name: String, age: Int) {
   override def productPrefix = "person: "
}

// prints "person: (Aaron,28)" instead of "Person(Aaron, 28)"
println(Person("Aaron", 28))
```

Answer (score 32):

It's not exactly hidden, but certainly a under advertised feature: *scalac -Xprint*.

As a illustration of the use consider the following source:

```
class A { "xx".r }
```

Compiling this with *scalac -Xprint:typer* outputs:

```
package <empty> {
  class A extends java.lang.Object with ScalaObject {
    def this(): A = {
      A.super.this();
      ()
    };
    scala.this.Predef.augmentString("xx").r
  }
}
```

Notice `scala.this.Predef.augmentString("xx").r`, which is a the application of the `implicit def augmentString` present in Predef.scala.

*scalac -Xprint:<phase>* will print the syntax tree after some compiler phase. To see the available phases use *scalac -Xshow-phases*.

This is a great way to learn what is going on behind the scenes.

Try with

`case class X(a:Int,b:String)`

using the *typer* phase to really feel how useful it is.

Answer (score 30):

You can define your own control structures. It's really just functions and objects and some syntactic sugar, but they look and behave like the real thing.

For example, the following code defines `dont {...} unless (cond)` and `dont {...} until (cond)`:

```
def dont(code: => Unit) = new DontCommand(code)

class DontCommand(code: => Unit) {
  def unless(condition: => Boolean) =
    if (condition) code

  def until(condition: => Boolean) = {
    while (!condition) {}
    code
  }
}
```

Now you can do the following:

```
/* This will only get executed if the condition is true */
dont {
  println("Yep, 2 really is greater than 1.")
} unless (2 > 1) 

/* Just a helper function */
var number = 0;
def nextNumber() = {
  number += 1
  println(number)
  number
}

/* This will not be printed until the condition is met. */
dont {
  println("Done counting to 5!")
} until (nextNumber() == 5)
```

Comment: Some more examples here: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/13072/alternatives-to-if-else-statement/13086#13086

Comment: I'd be curious if someone knows a way to define if-then-else blocks with optional else that type-check like the standard ones.

Comment: @Philippe: `zif[A : Zero](cond: => Boolean)(t: => A): A = if(cond) t else mzero`. Requires Scalaz.

Answer (score 26):

[`@switch`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/annotation/switch.html) annotation in Scala 2.8:

> An annotation to be applied to a match
>   expression. If present, the compiler
>   will verify that the match has been
>   compiled to a tableswitch or
>   lookupswitch, and issue an error if it
>   instead compiles into a series of
>   conditional expressions.

Example:

```
scala> val n = 3
n: Int = 3

scala> import annotation.switch
import annotation.switch

scala> val s = (n: @switch) match {
     |   case 3 => "Three"
     |   case _ => "NoThree"
     | }
<console>:6: error: could not emit switch for @switch annotated match
       val s = (n: @switch) match {
```

Answer (score 26):

Dunno if this is really hidden, but I find it quite nice.

Typeconstructors that take 2 type parameters can be written in infix notation

```
object Main {                                                                   
  class FooBar[A, B]

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    var x: FooBar[Int, BigInt] = null
    var y: Int FooBar BigInt   = null
  }
}
```

Comment: Nice! I can imagine that being sometimes useful in improving readability. For example `var foo2barConverter: Foo ConvertTo Bar` would make the order of type parameters self evident.

Comment: I sometimes do this in code that uses PartialFunction to some extent: type ~>[A, B] = PartialFunction[A, B]

Answer (score 24):

Scala 2.8 introduced default and named arguments, which made possible the addition of a new "copy" method that Scala adds to case classes.  If you define this:

```
case class Foo(a: Int, b: Int, c: Int, ... z:Int)
```

and you want to create a new Foo that's like an existing Foo, only with a different "n" value, then you can just say:

```
foo.copy(n = 3)
```

Comment: WARNING: copy method will not be overriden if you inherit one case class from another. So you have to override it manually

Comment: Related: Cleaner way to update nested structures http://stackoverflow.com/q/3900307/203968

Comment: case class is no longer (Scala 2.8) allowed to inherit from a case class. Thank you lord of Scala for deprecating this unholy inheritance.

Answer (score 24):

in scala 2.8 you can add @specialized to your generic classes/methods. This will create special versions of the class for primitive types (extending AnyVal) and save the cost of un-necessary boxing/unboxing :
`class Foo[@specialized T]...`

You can select a subset of AnyVals :
`class Foo[@specialized(Int,Boolean) T]...`

Comment: Is there a longer explanation that you could point me to? I'd like to learn more.

Answer (score 23):

You can designate a call-by-name parameter (EDITED: this is different then a lazy parameter!) to a function and it will not be evaluated until used by the function (EDIT: in fact, it will be reevaluated every time it is used).  See [this faq](http://scala.sygneca.com/faqs/language#what-s-the-difference-between-a-lazy-argument-a-no-arg-function-argument-and-a-lazy-value) for details

```
class Bar(i:Int) {
    println("constructing bar " + i)
    override def toString():String = {
        "bar with value: " + i
    }
}

// NOTE the => in the method declaration.  It indicates a lazy paramter
def foo(x: => Bar) = {
    println("foo called")
    println("bar: " + x)
}


foo(new Bar(22))

/*
prints the following:
foo called
constructing bar 22
bar with value: 22
*/
```

Comment: I thought "x: => Bar" meant that x was a function that took no parameters and returned a Bar.  So, "new bar(22)" is just an anonymous function, and is evaluated as a function like any other function.

Comment: "x: ()=>Bar" defines x a function that takes no parameters and returns a Bar.  x: => Bar defines x as call by name.  Take a look at http://scala.sygneca.com/faqs/language#what-s-the-difference-between-a-lazy-argument-a-no-arg-function-argument-and-a-lazy-value for more details

Comment: What you show is call-by-name parameters. Lazy parameters aren't implemented yet: https://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/ticket/240

Comment: I think that you can use it as a lazy param if you do something like `lazy val xx: Bar = x` in your method and from that moment on you only use `xx`.

Answer (score 23):

Extending the language. I always wanted to do something like this in Java (couldn't). But in Scala I can have:

```
  def timed[T](thunk: => T) = {
    val t1 = System.nanoTime
    val ret = thunk
    val time = System.nanoTime - t1
    println("Executed in: " + time/1000000.0 + " millisec")
    ret
  }
```

and then write:

```
val numbers = List(12, 42, 3, 11, 6, 3, 77, 44)
val sorted = timed {   // "timed" is a new "keyword"!
  numbers.sortWith(_<_)
}
println(sorted)
```

and get

```
Executed in: 6.410311 millisec
List(3, 3, 6, 11, 12, 42, 44, 77)
```

Answer (score 20):

You can use `locally` to introduce a local block without causing semicolon inference issues.

**Usage:**

```
scala> case class Dog(name: String) {
     |   def bark() {
     |     println("Bow Vow")
     |   }
     | }
defined class Dog

scala> val d = Dog("Barnie")
d: Dog = Dog(Barnie)

scala> locally {
     |   import d._
     |   bark()
     |   bark()
     | }
Bow Vow
Bow Vow
```

---

`locally` is defined in "Predef.scala" as:

```
@inline def locally[T](x: T): T = x
```

Being inline, it does not impose any additional overhead.

Comment: This is explained better at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3237727/what-does-predef-locally-do-and-how-is-it-different-from-predef-identity

Answer (score 17):

**placeholder syntax for anonymous functions**

From The Scala Language Specification:

```
SimpleExpr1 ::= '_'
```

> An expression (of syntactic category `Expr`) may contain embedded underscore symbols `_` at places where identifiers are legal. Such an expression represents an anonymous function where subsequent occurrences of underscores denote successive parameters.

From [Scala Language Changes](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/43):

```
_ + 1                  x => x + 1
_ * _                  (x1, x2) => x1 * x2
(_: Int) * 2           (x: Int) => x * 2
if (_) x else y        z => if (z) x else y
_.map(f)               x => x.map(f)
_.map(_ + 1)           x => x.map(y => y + 1)
```

Using this you could do something like:

```
def filesEnding(query: String) =
  filesMatching(_.endsWith(query))
```

Comment: This should be referred to as 'placeholder syntax for anonymous functions'. Implicit has a distinct meaning in Scala, and it isn't related to this.

Comment: The link has a non-obvious relationship to the answer. "implicit" is not the correct term for this.  As above it should be "placeholder."

Comment: It is not really "hidden", I have seen this usage in nearly all the tutorials on Scala I have read... :-) But I appreciate the formal definition I haven't seen yet.

Comment: @PhiLho maybe it was less well known in 2009. i don't know.

Comment: I missed the original date, as only the last edit date is shown. And well, not all features explained in this thread are "hidden". Cool thread and good answer anyway.

Answer (score 17):

[Early Initialization:](http://programming-scala.labs.oreilly.com/ch06.html)

```
trait AbstractT2 {
  println("In AbstractT2:")
  val value: Int
  val inverse = 1.0/value
  println("AbstractT2: value = "+value+", inverse = "+inverse)
}

val c2c = new {
  // Only initializations are allowed in pre-init. blocks.
  // println("In c2c:")
  val value = 10
} with AbstractT2

println("c2c.value = "+c2c.value+", inverse = "+c2c.inverse)
```

Output:

```
In AbstractT2:  
AbstractT2: value = 10, inverse = 0.1  
c2c.value = 10, inverse = 0.1
```

> We instantiate an anonymous inner
>   class, initializing the `value` field
>   in the block, before the `with
>   AbstractT2` clause. This guarantees
>   that `value` is initialized before the
>   body of `AbstractT2` is executed, as
>   shown when you run the script.

Comment: The construct is called "early initialization."

Answer (score 17):

You can compose structural types with the 'with' keyword

```
object Main {
  type A = {def foo: Unit}
  type B = {def bar: Unit}

  type C = A with B

  class myA {
    def foo: Unit = println("myA.foo")
  }


  class myB {
    def bar: Unit = println("myB.bar")
  }
  class myC extends myB {
    def foo: Unit = println("myC.foo")
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = { 
    val a: A = new myA 
    a.foo
    val b: C = new myC 
    b.bar
    b.foo
  }
}
```

Answer (score 16):

Implicit definitions, particularly conversions.

For example, assume a function which will format an input string to fit to a size, by replacing the middle of it with "...":

```
def sizeBoundedString(s: String, n: Int): String = {
  if (n < 5 && n < s.length) throw new IllegalArgumentException
  if (s.length > n) {
    val trailLength = ((n - 3) / 2) min 3
    val headLength = n - 3 - trailLength
    s.substring(0, headLength)+"..."+s.substring(s.length - trailLength, s.length)
  } else s
}
```

You can use that with any String, and, of course, use the toString method to convert anything. But you could also write it like this:

```
def sizeBoundedString[T](s: T, n: Int)(implicit toStr: T => String): String = {
  if (n < 5 && n < s.length) throw new IllegalArgumentException
  if (s.length > n) {
    val trailLength = ((n - 3) / 2) min 3
    val headLength = n - 3 - trailLength
    s.substring(0, headLength)+"..."+s.substring(s.length - trailLength, s.length)
  } else s
}
```

And then, you could pass classes of other types by doing this:

```
implicit def double2String(d: Double) = d.toString
```

Now you can call that function passing a double:

```
sizeBoundedString(12345.12345D, 8)
```

The last argument is implicit, and is being passed automatically because of the implicit de declaration. Furthermore, "s" is being *treated* like a String inside sizeBoundedString because there is an implicit conversion from it to String.

Implicits of this type are better defined for uncommon types to avoid unexpected conversions. You can also explictly pass a conversion, and it will still be implicitly used inside sizeBoundedString:

```
sizeBoundedString(1234567890L, 8)((l : Long) => l.toString)
```

You can also have multiple implicit arguments, but then you must either pass all of them, or not pass any of them. There is also a shortcut syntax for implicit conversions:

```
def sizeBoundedString[T <% String](s: T, n: Int): String = {
  if (n < 5 && n < s.length) throw new IllegalArgumentException
  if (s.length > n) {
    val trailLength = ((n - 3) / 2) min 3
    val headLength = n - 3 - trailLength
    s.substring(0, headLength)+"..."+s.substring(s.length - trailLength, s.length)
  } else s
}
```

This is used exactly the same way.

Implicits can have any value. They can be used, for instance, to hide library information. Take the following example, for instance:

```
case class Daemon(name: String) {
  def log(msg: String) = println(name+": "+msg)
}

object DefaultDaemon extends Daemon("Default")

trait Logger {
  private var logd: Option[Daemon] = None
  implicit def daemon: Daemon = logd getOrElse DefaultDaemon

  def logTo(daemon: Daemon) = 
    if (logd == None) logd = Some(daemon) 
    else throw new IllegalArgumentException

  def log(msg: String)(implicit daemon: Daemon) = daemon.log(msg)
}

class X extends Logger {
  logTo(Daemon("X Daemon"))

  def f = {
    log("f called")
    println("Stuff")
  }

  def g = {
    log("g called")(DefaultDaemon)
  }
}

class Y extends Logger {
  def f = {
    log("f called")
    println("Stuff")
  }
}
```

In this example, calling "f" in an Y object will send the log to the default daemon, and on an instance of X to the Daemon X daemon. But calling g on an instance of X will send the log to the explicitly given DefaultDaemon.

While this simple example can be re-written with overload and private state, implicits do not require private state, and can be brought into context with imports.

Answer (score 13):

Maybe not too hidden, but I think this is useful:

```
@scala.reflect.BeanProperty
var firstName:String = _
```

This will automatically generate a getter and setter for the field that matches bean convention.

Further description at [developerworks](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-scala03268.html)

Comment: And you can make shortcut for it if you use it a lot, e.g.: import scala.reflect.{BeanProperty => BP}

Answer (score 13):

Implicit arguments in closures.

A function argument can be marked as implicit just as with methods. Within the scope of the body of the function the implicit parameter is visible and eligible for implicit resolution:

```
trait Foo { def bar }

trait Base {
  def callBar(implicit foo: Foo) = foo.bar
}

object Test extends Base {
  val f: Foo => Unit = { implicit foo =>
    callBar
  }
  def test = f(new Foo {
    def bar = println("Hello")
  })
}
```

Answer (score 12):

Build infinite data structures with Scala's `Stream`s :
http://www.codecommit.com/blog/scala/infinite-lists-for-the-finitely-patient

Answer (score 12):

Result types are dependent on implicit resolution.   This can give you a form of multiple dispatch:

```
scala> trait PerformFunc[A,B] { def perform(a : A) : B }
defined trait PerformFunc

scala> implicit val stringToInt = new PerformFunc[String,Int] {
  def perform(a : String)  = 5
}
stringToInt: java.lang.Object with PerformFunc[String,Int] = $anon$1@13ccf137

scala> implicit val intToDouble = new PerformFunc[Int,Double] {
  def perform(a : Int) = 1.0
}
intToDouble: java.lang.Object with PerformFunc[Int,Double] = $anon$1@74e551a4

scala> def foo[A, B](x : A)(implicit z : PerformFunc[A,B]) : B = z.perform(x)
foo: [A,B](x: A)(implicit z: PerformFunc[A,B])B

scala> foo("HAI")
res16: Int = 5

scala> foo(1)
res17: Double = 1.0
```

Comment: That might be the case, but the session above is misleading. The definition of `foo` uses an `a` which must have been present in the environment prior to the execution of these commands. I assume you meant `z.perform(x)`.

Answer (score 4):

### Scala's equivalent of Java double brace initializer.

Scala allows you to create an anonymous subclass with the body of the class (the constructor) containing statements to initialize the instance of that class.

This pattern is very useful when building component-based user interfaces (for example Swing , Vaadin) as it allows to create UI components and declare their properties more concisely.

See http://spot.colorado.edu/~reids/papers/how-scala-experience-improved-our-java-development-reid-2011.pdf for more information.

Here is an example of creating a Vaadin button:

```
val button = new Button("Click me"){
 setWidth("20px")
 setDescription("Click on this")
 setIcon(new ThemeResource("icons/ok.png"))
}
```

Answer (score 3):

### Excluding members from `import` statements

Suppose you want to use a `Logger` that contains a `println` and a `printerr` method, but you only want to use the one for error messages, and keep the good old `Predef.println` for standard output. You could do this:

```
val logger = new Logger(...)
import logger.printerr
```

but if `logger` also contains another twelve methods that you would like to import and use, it becomes inconvenient to list them. You could instead try:

```
import logger.{println => donotuseprintlnt, _}
```

but this still "pollutes" the list of imported members. Enter the über-powerful wildcard:

```
import logger.{println => _, _}
```

and that will do *just the right thing*™.

Answer (score 2):

`require` method (defined in `Predef`) that allow you to define additional function constraints that would be checked during run-time. Imagine that you developing yet another twitter client and you need to limit tweet length up to 140 symbols. Moreover you can't post empty tweet.

```
def post(tweet: String) = {
  require(tweet.length < 140 && tweet.length > 0) 
  println(tweet)
 }
```

Now calling post with inappropriate length argument will cause an exception:

```
scala> post("that's ok")
that's ok

scala> post("")
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed
    at scala.Predef$.require(Predef.scala:145)
    at .post(<console>:8)

scala> post("way to looooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong tweet") 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed
    at scala.Predef$.require(Predef.scala:145)
    at .post(<console>:8)
```

You can write multiple requirements or even add description to each:

```
def post(tweet: String) = {
  require(tweet.length > 0, "too short message")
  require(tweet.length < 140, "too long message")
  println(tweet)
}
```

Now exceptions are verbose:

```
scala> post("")
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: too short message
    at scala.Predef$.require(Predef.scala:157)
    at .post(<console>:8)
```

One more example is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7007805/an-example-of-functional-programming-in-scala/7008171#7008171).

---

### Bonus

You can perform an action every time requirement fails:

```
scala> var errorcount = 0
errorcount: Int = 0

def post(tweet: String) = {
  require(tweet.length > 0, {errorcount+=1})
  println(tweet)
  }

scala> errorcount
res14: Int = 0

scala> post("")
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: ()
    at scala.Predef$.require(Predef.scala:157)
    at .post(<console>:9)
...

scala> errorcount
res16: Int = 1
```

Comment: `require` is not a reserved word. It's but a method defined in `Predef`.

Answer (score 1):

Traits with **`abstract override`** methods are a feature in Scala that is as not widely advertised as many others. The intend of methods with the `abstract override` modifier is to do some operations and delegating the call to `super`. Then these traits have to be mixed-in with concrete implementations of their `abstract override` methods.

```
trait A {
  def a(s : String) : String
}

trait TimingA extends A {
  abstract override def a(s : String) = {
    val start = System.currentTimeMillis
    val result = super.a(s)
    val dur = System.currentTimeMillis-start
    println("Executed a in %s ms".format(dur))
    result
  }
}

trait ParameterPrintingA extends A {
  abstract override def a(s : String) = {
    println("Called a with s=%s".format(s))
    super.a(s)
  }
}

trait ImplementingA extends A {
  def a(s: String) = s.reverse
}

scala> val a = new ImplementingA with TimingA with ParameterPrintingA

scala> a.a("a lotta as")
Called a with s=a lotta as
Executed a in 0 ms
res4: String = sa attol a
```

While my example is really not much more than a poor mans AOP, I used these *Stackable Traits* much to my liking to build Scala interpreter instances with predefined imports, custom bindings and classpathes. The *Stackable Traits* made it possible to create my factory along the lines of `new InterpreterFactory with JsonLibs with LuceneLibs` and then have useful imports and scope varibles for the users scripts.