# What does Predef.locally do, and how is it different from Predef.identity

Tags: scala

Looking through the Scala 2.8 Predef class, I find that there is a method "locally".  As near as I can tell, it's the same as Predef.identity, except for having the "@inline" annotation.  What's it for, and why is it important enough to be in Predef (and thus usable anywhere in Scala)?

Comment: See: http://www.scala-lang.org/node/3594

Comment: Wow, I was actually a part of that thread and forgot all about it.  If you make this an answer rather than a comment, I'll accept it and close the question

Comment: Hmm. I'd still be interested what's the difference between `identity` and `locally`.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

It is discussed here: http://www.scala-lang.org/node/3594

The idea was to avoid the programmer error of confusing a 'dangling' local block with the template of an object/class/trait.

```
object test {
  object a
  {
    val x = 1
  }

  object b

  { // oops, extra newline disassociates this block with the object b
    val x = 1
  }
}
test.a.x
//test.b.x // doesn't compile
```

If the programmer really wants that block to stand alone, `locally` could be used:

```
object test {
  object a
  {
    val x = 1
  }

  object b

  locally {
    val x = 1
  }
}
```

This thread also suggested that the first code would produce a deprecation warning. This has not yet been added.