# Scala: "recursive value ... needs type" but I use Java types only

Tags: scala

```
object Rec extends App {
  val outStream = new java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream
  {
    val out = new java.io.PrintStream(new java.io.BufferedOutputStream(outStream))
  }
}
```

This seemingly simple code causes a compile error:

```
$ scalac rec.scala
rec.scala:2: error: recursive value out needs type
  val outStream = new java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream
                  ^
one error found
```

But I don't see what is "recursive."

Scala compiler version 2.11.7 -- Copyright 2002-2013, LAMP/EPFL

Background: I was trying to write a unit test on `println` with [`Console.withOut`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Console$@withOut[T](out:java.io.PrintStream)(thunk:=>T):T)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After putting braces where they belong code looks like this:

```
object Rec extends App {
  val outStream = new java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream {
    val out = new java.io.PrintStream(new java.io.BufferedOutputStream(outStream))
  }
}
```

and this is how you create object of an anonymous class with a member `out` that uses the defined object recursively (`outStream` uses `outStream` in its definition).

I believe this is what you wanted to do

```
object Rec extends App {
  val outStream = new java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream
  val out = new java.io.PrintStream(new java.io.BufferedOutputStream(outStream))
}
```

If you for some reason need to create another scope, you can use `locally`

[What does Predef.locally do, and how is it different from Predef.identity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3237727/what-does-predef-locally-do-and-how-is-it-different-from-predef-identity)

Comment: Thanks for telling me about `locally`

Answer (score 4):

You are assigning a value to `outStream` by invoking stuff to which you pass on the `outStream` (I marked it in CAPS). Hence the recursion.

```
object Rec extends App {
  val OUTSTREAM = new java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream
  {
    val out = new java.io.PrintStream(new java.io.BufferedOutputStream(OUTSTREAM))
  }
}
```