# An example of functional programming in scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I'm studying scala. It's very promising, thanks to Odersky and all the other authors for their great work.

I took a euler problem ([http://projecteuler.net/](http://projecteuler.net)) to have a more-then-minimal example. And I'm trying to go the functional way. So this is not a "please answer me immediatly or my boss will kill me" but a "please if you've got time, can you help a imperative language programmer to take a journey in the functional world?"

Problem: I want a class for poker hands. A poker Hand is composed by a number of Card, from 0 to 5. I'd like to build the list of Cards one and for all, that is: my Hand class will be immutable, if I want to add a card, then I create a new Hand object.
So I need a collection of Card that can be created as "val", not as var. 
First step: constructors, one for each number of cards. But Card's collection is handled in each constructor, so I must have it as var!

Here's the code, Card class is simply a Suit and a Value, passed to constructor as a string ("5S" is the 5 of spades):

```
class Hand(mycards : List[Card]) {
  // this should be val, I guess
  private var cards : List[Card] = {
    if (mycards.length>5)
      throw new IllegalArgumentException(
        "Illegal number of cards: " + mycards.length);
    sortCards(mycards)
  }

  // full hand constructor
  def this(a : String, b : String, c : String, d : String, e : String) = {
      this(Nil)

      // assign cards
      val cardBuffer = new ListBuffer[Card]()
      if ( a!=null ) cardBuffer += new Card(a)
      if ( b!=null ) cardBuffer += new Card(b)
      if ( c!=null ) cardBuffer += new Card(c)
      if ( d!=null ) cardBuffer += new Card(d)
      if ( e!=null ) cardBuffer += new Card(e)
      cards = sortCards(cardBuffer.toList)
  }
  // hand with less then 5 cards
  def this(a : String, b : String, c : String, d : String) = this(a,b,c,d,null)
  def this(a : String, b : String, c : String) = this(a, b, c, null)
  def this(a : String, b : String) = this(a, b, null)
  def this(a : String) = this(a, null)
  def this() = this(Nil)

/* removed */
}
```

Do you know how to make it the true functional way?
Thanks.

PS: if you really want to know, it's problem 54.

Comment: Generally, `null` is not desired in functional. Scala uses `Option` _monad_ for that cases (Haskell has `Maybe`).
[Option tutorial](http://www.codecommit.com/blog/scala/the-option-pattern)

Comment: Added sordCard() to main constructor, thanks to @Rotsor for his help.

Answer (score 7):

My answer is not about *functional* aspect of scala, but your code is possible to write shortly using scala sugar:

```
class Hand(val mycards: List[Card]) {
  require (mycards.size <= 5,"can't be more than five cards")
  def this(input: String*) = { 
    this(input.map(c => new Card(c)).toList)
  }
}
```

`input: String*` in auxiliary constructor says that you can have variable number of arguments (even thousand of strings). 
I'm getting input and invoke creation for each new Card with `map` function, and then pass result to parent constructor which has it's own **requirement**. 
(BTW, *mapping* from string to Card can be done anonymously, in that manner: `this(input.map(new Card(_)).toList)`)

`class Hand(val mycards: List[Card]) {...`

Is equable to

```
class Hand(cards: List[Card]) {
val mycards = cards 
...
```

From now on, if you will try to create more than five cards in hand you'll get `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException`:

```
scala> class Card(s: String) {println("Im a :"+s)}
defined class Card

scala> new Hand("one","two","three","four","five","six")
Im a :one
Im a :two
Im a :three
Im a :four
Im a :five
Im a :six
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: can't be more than five card
    at scala.Predef$.require(Predef.scala:157)
    at Hand.<init>(<console>:9)
```

Answer (score 5):

Well, the the `var` in the code below comes from you not initializing `cards` from the main constructor:

```
// this should be val, I guess
private var cards : List[Card] = {
  if (mycards.length>5)
    throw new IllegalArgumentException(
      "Illegal number of cards: " + mycards.length);
  sortCards(mycards)
}
```

So what you need to do is fix the secondary constructor:

```
// full hand constructor
def this(a : String, b : String, c : String, d : String, e : String) = {
    this(Nil)

    // assign cards
    val cardBuffer = new ListBuffer[Card]()
    if ( a!=null ) cardBuffer += new Card(a)
    if ( b!=null ) cardBuffer += new Card(b)
    if ( c!=null ) cardBuffer += new Card(c)
    if ( d!=null ) cardBuffer += new Card(d)
    if ( e!=null ) cardBuffer += new Card(e)
    cards = sortCards(cardBuffer.toList)
}
```

THe problemn is simple: you want a list of cards formed by non-null Strings. If I were you, I'd just avoid passing nulls, but... Anyway, the best way to handle that is to convert this into options. The conversion is simple: `Option(a)` will return `Some(a)` is `a` is not null, and `None` if it is. If you compose a list of that, you can then `flatten` it to remove the `None` and convert `Some(a)` back into `a`. In other words:

```
def this(a : String, b : String, c : String, d : String, e : String) = 
    this(List(a, b, c, d, e).map(Option(_)).flatten.map(Card(_)))
```

Answer (score 4):

Because in this example you are only allowed to use five cards I would check this at compile time with the use of a Tuple5:

```
type HandType = (ACard, ACard, ACard, ACard, ACard)
case class Hand(h: HandType)

abstract class ACard {
  def exists: Boolean
}
case class Card(value: Int, color: Color) extends ACard {
  def exists = true
}
case object NoCard extends ACard {
  def exists = false
}

abstract class Color(val c: Int)
case object H extends Color(1)
case object C extends Color(2)
case object S extends Color(3)
case object D extends Color(4)
case object NoColor extends Color(0)

implicit def tuple2Card(t: (Int, Color)) = Card(t._1, t._2)

val h1 = Hand((Card(4, H), Card(6, S), Card(2, S), Card(8, D), NoCard))
val h2 = Hand((4 -> H, 6 -> S, 2 -> S, 8 -> D, NoCard))

println(h1)
println(h2)
h1.h.productIterator foreach { c => println(c.asInstanceOf[ACard].exists) }
```

Of course in another example when there can be an unspecific number of elements you need to check them at runtime. `productIterator` only returns a Iterator[Any] but when you use your cards directly by the field-identifiers (_1 .. _5) you will get an `ACard`.

Comment: Use of tuples is interesting, even if @om-nom-nom solution is more concise. But your solution provides only the full constructor with 5 arguments, and this could be a problem. The example requires to calculate the rank of the hand, and I have managed to do it this way: search for a rank like a couple, if there is such a rank, extract the couple from the hand, and iterate on the remaining cards. To create the sub-hand, I should invoke the full contructor with a variable number of NoCard. Maybe it's not that hard, but a variable args constructor seems the perfect choice.

Comment: If one really wants to represent a limited-length list checked at compile time, a better option would be something like `Option[(Card, Option[(Card, Option[(Card, Option[(Card, Option[Card])])])])]` :)

Comment: Although the above looks ugly without some type-level magic, it still can be shortened to `OC[OC[OC[OC[OC[Unit]]]]]` with simple type aliases.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, `null` is evil, use `Option` instead. Secondly, Scala supports default parameters. So instead of creating all the constructors, you might just wanna use one of them like this:

```
def this(a: String = null, ..., e: String = null) = ...
```

or with `Option`, which is safer.

```
def this(a: Option[String] = None, ..., e: Option[String] = None) = {
   this(Nil)

   val cardBuffer = new ListBuffer[Card]()
   a foreach { cardBuffer += new Card(_) }
   b foreach { cardBuffer += new Card(_) }
   c foreach { cardBuffer += new Card(_) }
   d foreach { cardBuffer += new Card(_) }
   e foreach { cardBuffer += new Card(_) }
   cards = sortCards(cardBuffer.toList)
}
```

So the cards are only added to the buffer if they "exist".

Comment: Who says you shouldn't? It is a simple trade-off between runtime and compile time.

Answer (score 1):

First, we need to fix a compile error in your `cards` field definition.

Note that in Scala you usually don't have to declare fields. Main constructor parameters already are fields! So, this can be written simpler:

```
class Hand(cards : List[Card]) {
  if (cards.length>5)
      throw new IllegalArgumentException(
        "Illegal number of cards: " + mycards.length);
```

Now we have mutability problem. If you want to program in functional style, everything should be immutable, so the "full hand constructor" is not functional at all: it has 6 side-effecting operations, last of which does not compile.

In functional setting, an object can't be modified after its constructor has terminated, so all the code after `this(Nil)` is useless. You already said that `cards` is `Nil`, what else do you want?! So, all the computations have to happen *before* the main constructor call. We'd like to remove `this(Nil)` from the top and add `this(sortCards(cardBuffer.toList))` to the bottom. Unfortunately, Scala does not allow that. Fortunately, it allows more options to achieve the same than java: first, you can use a nested block like this:

```
this({
  val cardBuffer = ... /* terrible imperativeness */
  sortCards(cardBuffer.toList)
})
```

second, you can use `apply` method instead of a constructor:

```
object Hand {
  def apply(a : String, b : String, c : String, d : String, e : String) = {
    val cardBuffer = ... /* terrible imperativeness */
    new Hand(sortCards(cardBuffer.toList))
  }
}
```

Now, let's start getting rid of imperative `ListBuffer`. First improvement would be to use `var` of type `List[Card]`. Making mutability more local will help to remove it later:

```
// assign cards
var cards = Nil
if ( e!=null ) cards = new Card(e) :: cards
if ( d!=null ) cards = new Card(d) :: cards
if ( c!=null ) cards = new Card(c) :: cards
if ( b!=null ) cards = new Card(b) :: cards
if ( a!=null ) cards = new Card(a) :: cards
sortCards(cards)
```

Okay, now we can see what exactly we are mutating and can easily remove that mutability:

```
val fromE = if ( e!=null ) new Card(e) :: Nil else Nil
val fromD = if ( d!=null ) new Card(d) :: fromE else fromE
val fromC = if ( c!=null ) new Card(c) :: fromD else fromD
val fromB = if ( b!=null ) new Card(b) :: fromC else fromC
val fromA = if ( a!=null ) new Card(a) :: fromB else fromB
sortCards(fromA)
```

Now we have a fair amount of code duplication. Let's remove that in a brute-force way (find a long duplicating piece of code and extract function)!

```
def prependCard(x : String, cards : List[Card]) = 
  if ( x!=null ) new Card(x) :: cards else cards
val cards = prependCard(a, prependCard(b, 
              prependCard(c, prependCard(d, 
                prependCard(e, Nil)
              ))
            ))
sortCards(cards)
```

Next, very important, transformation would be to replace nullable references with the values of `Option` type, or remove the empty card concept altogether.

**Update:**

As requested, I am adding an example of usage of the `apply` method. Notice that it is declared in `object Hand`, not `class Hand`, so it doesn't need an instance of the class (it's similar to static method in java). We just apply the object to parameters: `val hand = Hand("5S", "5S", "5S", "5S", "5S")`.

Comment: My code compile, but I took out too many lines for the snippet. Your answer is a very good tutorial on removing terrible imperativness, thx. I tried and I didn't manage to use the apply method. My understanding is that I need a hand object to use it, but using the default ctor is not possible, 'causse I end up with 2 assignemnt to card list. Can you provide a simple usage example, please?

Comment: Added the usage example of `apply`. I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Attempt using varargs, overloaded + operator, repeated addition in constructor, and Set to eliminate duplicate cards.

```
package poker

class Hand(private val cards:Set[Card] = Set.empty[Card]) {
  def + (card:Card) = {
    val hand = new Hand(cards + card)
    require(hand.length > length, "Card %s duplicated".format(card))
    require(hand.length <= Hand.maxLength, "Hand length > %d".format(Hand.maxLength))
    hand
  }
  def length = cards.size
  override def toString = cards.mkString("(", ",", ")")
}

object Hand {
  val maxLength = 5
  def apply(cards:Card*):Hand = cards.foldLeft(Hand())(_ + _)
  private def apply() = new Hand()
}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------//


class Card private (override val toString:String) 

object Card {
  def apply(card:String) = {
    require(cardMap.contains(card), "Card %s does not exist".format(card))
    cardMap(card)
  }

  def cards = cardMap.values.toList

  private val cardMap = {
    val ranks = Range(2,9).inclusive.map { _.toString } ++ List("T", "J", "Q", "K", "A")
    val suits = List("c","d","h","s")
    (for(r <- ranks; s <- suits) yield (r + s -> new Card(r + s))).toMap
  } 
}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------//

object Test extends App {
  Array("1f", "Ac").foreach { s =>
    try {
      printf("Created card %s successfully\n",Card(s))
    } catch {
      case e:Exception => printf("Input string %s - %s \n", s, e.getMessage)
    }
  }
  println

  for(i <- 0 to 6) {
    val cards = Card.cards.slice(0, i)
    makeHand(cards)
  }
  println

  val cards1 = List("Ac","Ad","Ac").map { Card(_) } 
  makeHand(cards1)
  println

  val hand1 = Hand(List("Ac","Ad").map { Card(_) }:_* )
  val card = Card("Ah")
  val hand2 = hand1 + card
  printf("%s + %s = %s\n", hand1, card, hand2)

  def makeHand(cards:List[Card]) =  
    try {
      val hand = Hand(cards: _*)
      printf("Created hand %s successfully\n",hand)
    } catch {
      case e:Exception => printf("Input %s - %s \n", cards, e.getMessage)
    }
}
```