# Is there a central site/page for "advanced Scala" topics?

Tags: scala

Despite having read "Programming in Scala" several times, I still often finds important Scala constructs that were not explained in the book, like

```
@uncheckedVariance
@specialized
```

and other strange constructs like

```
new { ... }  // No class name!
```

and so on.

I find this rather frustrating, considering that the book was written by the Scala "inventor" himself, and others.

I tried to read the language specification, but it's made for academics, rather than practicing programmers. It made my head spin.

Is there a website for "Everything "Programming in Scala" Didn't Tell You" ?

There was the [daily-scala](http://daily-scala.blogspot.com/) Blog, but it died over a year ago.

Comment: StackOverflow, perhaps?

Comment: Possibly useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1025181/hidden-features-of-scala/

Comment: @Rex. LOL! That's not quite it. It's not about finding the answer to question I have, but rather to question that I don't have yet...

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Currently, we're working on a central documentation site for scala-lang.org. We're hoping that this solves a lot of the documentation issues that new users face. More details on this effort can be found at http://heather.miller.am/blog/2011/07/improving-scala-documentation/, but in summary...

Believe it or not, there are a lot of documents that the Scala team has produced but which simply aren't in HTML or are otherwise difficult to find. Such as Martin's new [Collections API](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/collections-api/collections.html), his document on [Arrays](http://www.scala-lang.org/sites/default/files/sids/cunei/Thu,%202009-10-01,%2013:54/arrays.pdf), or Adriaan's on [Type Constructor Inference](http://adriaanm.github.com/research/2010/10/06/new-in-scala-2.8-type-constructor-inference/).

One goal of such a site is to collect all of this documentation in one place, in a searchable, organized, and easy-to-navigate format.

Another goal is to collect excellent community documentation out there, and to put it in the same place as well. For that, we are actively looking for quality (article/overview-like) material with maintainers. Examples include the [Scala Style Guide](http://davetron5000.github.com/scala-style/), and Daniel Spiewak's [Scala for Java Refugees](http://www.codecommit.com/blog/scala/roundup-scala-for-java-refugees).

Yet another goal is to make it easy for contributors to participate- so the site is built from RST source, which will live in a documentation-only github repo at https://github.com/scala/scala-docs.

So, in short, something better is on it's way, and contributors are very welcome to participate.

**EDIT:** http://docs.scala-lang.org is now live.

Several documents considered to be rather detailed or even obscure are already available. This includes all "Scala Improvement Proposals" (the proposals produced when new language features are suggested, and which are usually very detailed, and written by the implementers themselves). Also available is the entire glossary from [Programming in Scala](http://www.artima.com/shop/programming_in_scala), Scala cheatsheets, amongst many other documents. The bottom-line of the site is to be community-focused and contribution-friendly-- so, free, and totally open. Suggested topics to cover are also welcome.

Comment: This sounds great! But I'm not sure if it will solve my problem. To summaries it, when you have already read a book that covers 95% of Scala (for some specific version), it's a pain if you have to read those 95% again just to get at the missing 5%. A single page with links to the more advanced/obscure features/constructs would be a real time-saver for "intermediate" Scala programmers.

Comment: Creating a cheat sheet which includes the Scala language features and its hidden features is a really good idea. There are already some paper for this, such as [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3820192/scala-cheatsheet-quickref), but they are not comprehensive. I started to create such a cheat sheet and include it to my German Scala tutorial.

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at [scalaz](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz) and [typelevel](http://typelevel.org/) librairies (shapeless, spire, etc.), they rely on many advanced features of Scala.

*scalaz was for a time part of typelevel, but it is no more the case.

Comment: I now mention typelevel.

Answer (score 5):

Josh Sureth's book goes a little beyond the usual.  It's not as far as I'd like but I'm not his core audience - still, there's a lot of good stuff in there.

http://www.manning.com/suereth

Answer (score 4):

- Scala IRC: irc://irc.freenode.net/scala
- Scala forum: http://scala-forum.org/
- Blogs: Just look at http://planetscala.com/
- Programming Scala (Wampler, Payne): http://ofps.oreilly.com/titles/9780596155957/
- Programming in Scala (Odersky, Venners, Spoon) - good but Scala 2.8: http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/

Comment: Programming in Scala has [a second edition](http://www.artima.com/shop/programming_in_scala_2ed) !!!

Answer (score 2):

The new documentation page is online:

[http://docs.scala-lang.org/](http://docs.scala-lang.org)

Answer (score 2):

I've kept a [library of advanced Scala resources](https://www.kifi.com/andrew/advanced-scala-resources), primarily talks and blog posts. It's updated pretty regularly as I find new, interesting content.

Happy to add new links to it if anyone has recommendations.

Answer (score 1):

Try to read SBT Source: https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/wiki
Its a good exercise. Also check out the book 'scala in depth' : http://www.manning.com/suereth/ by 
Joshua D. Suereth

Comment: I don't buy the "Good Programmers Don't Need Comments" coding style, I'm afraid. Professional programmers should write code so that *other* programmers can understand it, IMO.

Comment: Who said that nobody need comments?

Comment: I've never used STB, as I prefer a build process that is not tied to a specific language, but apparently it's very good. What I did is I looked at 3 random source files, and they had on the average two lines of comments per file, one of them being "TODO ..." I'm a "corporate developer", where code readability is valued as much as correctness, not an "OSS hacker", so in my book, this falls in the "bad code example" category. In other words, I would not keep my job if I coded like that.

Comment: Ok I see your point. But you ask for scala code which uses advanced concepts, so does SBT. I did not read the whole SBT Source and it was just an example. If that code couldn't satisfy what your were looking for then that's ok.

Answer (score 1):

I believe there are a lot of good answer here. But as a sharing of experience. I have been coding Scala for 2 year (not my full time job), and been progressively better at it. My project is 97% Scala, and I have been able to do most of it with:

1. Programming Scala
2. The scala-user list
3. Stackoverflow

This cover most of the need for the "user" side of Scala, meaning all you need to create working application. However if you want to write some more complex code, or create powerful typed libraries you definitely need more.

If you want to go beyond the basics and are prepared to delve deeply into type system, and libraries, then the alternatives I use:

1. Use the community, scala enthusiast are really nice. I have worked with folks form Specs, Scalaz and Lift.
2. IRC is really good and some of the core contributors to some of the big library frequently show up.
3. Jump to source code, but don't try to understand everything. Scala type system can be daunting, however you normally don't need to understand 100% of it to use it.
4. If you really need to get into the nitty gritty details, hit the language specs, development list, and get to know the key people.

However you can really be very effective in Scala without needing to understand every single bit of the language.