# What is this Scala syntax called: new C { i = 5 } // there's a block after the new

Tags: scala

I encountered this syntax in someone else's Scala code, and don't remember reading about it:

```
val c  = new C { i = 5 }
```

It appears that the block after the **new C** is equivalent to:

```
val c = new C
c.i = 5
```

assuming a class definition like:

```
class C {
  var ii = 1
  def i_=(v: Int) { ii = v }
  def i = ii
}
```

What is this syntax called in Scala? I want to read more about it, but I can't find it described in *Programming in Scala* or elsewhere.

Comment: You cannot reassign `ii` in class `C`: `ii` is a `val`.

Comment: Sorry, typo in my example. Edited.

Comment: Still doesn't compile with the `new C { i = 5 }` part.

Comment: Fixed again, added "def i = ii" (though why that's needed is another question), and then I ran it through the compiler. Serves me right for being sloppy transcribing something I did in the REPL.

Comment: The corresponding accessor is needed for the syntactic sugar for the mutator to work as per the Scala Reference.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are instantiating an **anonymous subclass** of `C`.

It is *not* equivalent to the code you've shown — try calling `getClass` on the two instances called `c` in your snippets.

Comment: Got it. The original code is just using that syntax to compactly initialize a Swing widget; the subclassing is not vital.

Comment: This idiom is mentioned in the SO "Hidden Features of Scala" [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1025181/hidden-features-of-scala/6661607#6661607).