# How to declare implicit arguments in higher order functions?

Tags: scala

I want IMPLICIT args in a higher order function, like:

func(arg1) { implicit (x, y) => x * y }

But the compiler says:

error: expected start of definition
val a = func("2", "4") { implicit (x, y) =>
                                  ^

- java version "1.7.0_40"
- Scala code runner version 2.10.2-RC2 -- Copyright 2002-2013, LAMP/EPFL

The runnable sample code:

```
object Test extends App {
    new Test().run
}

class Test {
    def run = {
        val a = func("2", "4") { (x, y) => // It's OK
            x * y
        }
        println("a: " + a)

        val b = gunc("2", "4") { implicit x => { implicit y => // It's OK
            x * y
        }}
        println("b: " + b)
    }

    def func(x: String, y: String)(f: (Int, Int) => Int) = f(x.toInt, y.toInt)
    def gunc(x: String, y: String)(g: Int => Int => Int) = g(x.toInt)(y.toInt)
    def hunc(x: String, y: String)(h: Tuple2[Int, Int] => Int) = h((x.toInt, y.toInt))
}
```

[ADD COMMENT]

I wonder...

We can declare as "implicit x => ..." with one arg.

It seems there is no way to declare two implicit args.

Comment: It obviously won't fix a problem, but why don't you update to **final** version of Scala, e.g. 2.10.2 or 2.10.3?

Comment: no reason => I update 2.10.2. 'obviously' means what? Scala Prog Lang Spec mentions this problem?

Comment: I said *obviously* because the way parser works (your issue is language syntax) isn't something that usually changes between release candidate and final versions. So, upgrading to a stable version won't fix this problem, but will bring you overall stability instead.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding:

```
val c = hunc("2", "4") { implicit pair => pair._1 * pair._2 }
```

Comment: Thank you. It works. But it is 'ONE arg' example not 'TWO args'.

Answer (score 1):

When you say `implicit y => y * 2` you're not
   declaring an implicit argument but mark the function as implicit,
    so you make an analog to this:

```
implicit val f1 = (y: Int) => y * 2
def func1(x: String, y: String)(f: Int => Int) = f(1)
func1("", "")(f1)
```

When you want to mark a function with two
   arguments as implicit you can do it this way:

```
implicit val f2 = (x: Int, y: Int) => y * 2
def func2(x: String, y: String)(f: (Int, Int) => Int) = f(1, 2)
func2("", "")(f2)
```

But you cannot do it so:
`func2("", "")(implicit (x, y) => x)`, in this particular case I just don't see any meaning to use implicits.

Also you can see this question, maybe you'll find some useful information [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12685591/implicit-keyword-before-a-parameter-in-anonymous-function-in-scala)