# Explain request passing in play framework

Tags: scala, playframework, request, action, implicit

I was trying this in playframework. When I came through this part, at first it seemed pretty straightforward but while trying to trace it I'm not able to understand how this works. I know what kind of parameter is accepted by apply method of Action but I couldn't get how request is available and how it can be passed to **Ok**. Can anyone show analogous example with simple definition in scala.

```
@Singleton
class HomeController @Inject()(configuration: Configuration, cc: ControllerComponents)(implicit assetsFinder: AssetsFinder)
  extends AbstractController(cc) {
  def tweets = Action { implicit request =>
    Ok(s"request is $request")
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have a look at the scaladoc. https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.mvc.Action

Comment: Actually I needed to know which scala syntax allows this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll try and simplify a bit:

```
trait A extends (String => String) { self => def apply() = this }
```

A effectively extends a function from String to String.

```
object A { def apply(f: String => String): A = new A { def apply(x: String) = f(x) } }
```

A's companion object actually implements A.

So you can now do this:

```
val f: String => String = _.toLowerCase
A(f)
```

This is valid Scala code.

You define `f` (`toLowerCase` on strings) and you pass it to the `apply` method of A.

This can also be written like this:

```
A { s => s.toLowerCase } // this way of putting it should remind you of Action { request => ... }
```

This is exactly how Play `Action` and `EssentialAction` works.

The other thing you ask is about `Ok`.

`Ok` is defined as a short version of `Status` with a set status code (200) and the given body (so something like `Ok("Hello world!")` will work.

On top of this there's the usual [string interpolation](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/string-interpolation.html) you should know about.

Answer (score 1):

Object [`Action`](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/mvc/Action.scala#L494-L500) extends trait [`DefaultActionBuilder`](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/mvc/Action.scala#L467-L473) extending trait [`ActionBuilder`](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/mvc/Action.scala#L301-L452). The latter has [method](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/mvc/Action.scala#L334-L347)

```
apply(block: R[B] => Result): Action[B]
```

In your case `request` is of type `Request[AnyContent]` i.e. `R` is `Request` and `B` is `AnyContent`, `Ok(s"request is $request")` is of type `Result`,

```
Action { implicit request =>
  Ok(s"request is $request")
}
```

is of type `Action[B]` i.e. `Action[AnyContent]`. So the syntax is just `apply` method of an object and a lambda as an argument of the method.

[What is the apply function in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9737352/what-is-the-apply-function-in-scala)

`foo(implicit x => ???)` is the same as `foo(x => { implicit val x_ = x; ??? })`.

[Implicit keyword before a parameter in anonymous function in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12685591/implicit-keyword-before-a-parameter-in-anonymous-function-in-scala)

`Ok` is just [`new Status(OK)`](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/mvc/Results.scala#L513-L514) i.e. `new Status(200)` and class [`Status`](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/mvc/Results.scala#L399-L505) has [method](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/mvc/Results.scala#L406-L416)

```
def apply[C](content: C)(implicit writeable: Writeable[C]): Result
```

i.e. `C` is now `String` and `content` is `s"request is $request"` (i.e. string `"request is " + request.toString`).

If you use IDE you can investigate similar inheritance hierarchies and types yourself.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The real thing I need to know is according to which scala construct are we able to pass request to Ok?

Comment: `Ok(s"request is $request")` is the same as `Ok.apply("request is" + request.toString)`. It's just function syntax in Scala (`f(x)` is the same as `f.apply(x)`) and string interpolation.