# Scala unbound placeholder parameter

Tags: scala, scala-2.10, string-interpolation

I am using the following code to meet my needs:

```
 (1 to 5)..map(i => s"\\x${i}")  // Produces List("\\x1", "\\x2", "\\x3", "\\x4", "\\x5")
```

But I would like to use a placeholder. According to [the string interpolator documentation](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/string-interpolation.html) :

```
(1 to 5).map(s"\\x${_}")
```

should expand to:

```
(1 to 5).map(StringContext("\\\\x","").s(_))
```

But the latter works, not the former, which throws an `error: unbound placeholder parameter` on `_`. Why?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I believe with the syntax:

```
(1 to 5).map(s"\\x${_}")
```

The compiler believes that the _ belongs to the `s` function in which case it won't work.  You can easily solve this by doing something like this:

```
(1 to 5).map(i => s"\\x${i}")
```

You might want to have a look at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1025181/hidden-features-of-scala/1083523#1083523) for further clarity on the rules for placeholders in relation to anonymous functions.

EDIT:
According to this post, the placeholder syntax used to work, so maybe this is a regression error or a feature that was never meant to work this way: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/scala-internals/G_54LGj0zpg/REZfyXZ6-RwJ

Comment: I added the solution that I was already using directly in my question. I would like to have more than beliefs if possible. `s` is not a function, it is a scala feature.

Comment: @MikaëlMayer well, no, it's not a language feature. It's defined here: http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.StringContext

You can also use raw"", f"" or even create your own string interpolators (json"", sql"",...)