# Scala function literals and unbound placeholder parameter

Tags: scala

I am trying to wrap my head around using underscore in function literals and the following has me stumped:

The following works:

```
def g(s: Int => Int) = 1.to(10).map(s(_))
g(_ * 2)
```

but this fails:

```
import scala.xml.Node
def f(s: Int => Node) = 1.to(10).map(s(_))
f(<p>{_}</p>)
```

The error being reported is:

```
Error:(11, 8) unbound placeholder parameter
f(<P>{_}</P>)
  ^
```

What explains this?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you simply can't use a placeholder like this inside an XML literal.

Comment: That seems arbitrary. Are there other types where underscore cannot be used like this?

Comment: Same situation happens in string interpolation. I am not certain, but it seems likely that the parser is looking for a complete expression inside braces (or after `$` in string interpolation), and `_` is not an expression by itself.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed this SO answer talking about placeholders in String: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16688830/53949