# 2 FoldLefts are Equal

Tags: scala

Why do both of the following `foldLeft`'s result in the same output?

**#1**

```
scala> List(1,2,3).foldLeft(List[Int]())( (acc, el) => acc :+ el)
res114: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)
```

And, now using `_ :+ _` as the `(B, A) => B` argument.

**#2**

```
scala> List(1,2,3).foldLeft(List[Int]())(_ :+ _)
res115: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)
```

In particular, the lack of explicitly appending to the `accumulator` in the second case confuses me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`_ :+ _` is simply a shorthand for `(x1, x2) => x1 :+ x2`, just as `list.map(_.toString)` is simply `list.map(x => x.toString)`.

See more on the placeholder syntax [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1025181/hidden-features-of-scala/1083523#1083523).

Comment: why can't i write `xs.foldLeft(List[Int]())(:+)` ?