# What is going on in the match functionality?

Tags: scala

I have a method:

```
  def replaceSpecialSymbols(str: String): String = str.collect {
    case '/'     => '-'
    case _ => _
  }.toString
```

Whe I try to build this code, I receive the error message: "error: unbound placeholder parameter case _   => _"

I know that I can use replaceAll. But I want to know what is going on in this case in Scala compiler.

Thank you.

Comment: Look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1025181/hidden-features-of-scala/1083523#1083523 for clarity on the rules for placeholders in relation to anonymous functions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `case x => x` — problem solved. Also, you can just use `map` instead of `collect` because it's an exhaustive match.

Or if you only need the first case, just remove that `case _ => _` altogether and keep using `collect`.

Comment: Erik thank you. I know how to solve this problem. I want to know why it does not work. What is wrong, why scala return this exception "unbound placeholder parameter".

Comment: @Nikolay, it happens because `_` is special in Scala. In particular, in pattern matches `_` means that corresponding pattern should be ignored - it does not bind the value to `_` identifier, so it does not make sense to use it as a standalone identifier.

Comment: Vladimir thank you. This is a good explanation. Can you post it like standalone answer?

Comment: Sorry, I missed the last part of your question — Vladimir's right: the first `_` is a pattern match; the second one is completely unrelated to the first one and Scala sees no reason for it to be there, so it says it's "unbound".

Comment: P.S. in other words, smth like `3 match { case _ => (_: Int) * 2 }` will compile because the `_` in the case body is meaningful because it's bound to its surrounding lambda expression; just a lone `_` means nothing.

Comment: Erik in your case I receive a function:
scala> 3 match { case _ => (_: Int) * 2 }
res13: Int => Int = <function1>