# Why does this lambda function can't work with `_` in Scala?

Tags: scala, lambda, functional-programming

In scala REPL, this works well

```
scala> (1 to 3).foreach(i => print(i + ","))
1,2,3,
```

But this won't work

```
scala> (1 to 3).foreach(print(_ + ","))
<console>:8: error: missing parameter type for expanded function ((x$1) => x$1.$plus(","))
              (1 to 3).foreach(print(_ + ","))
```

If I remove the `+","` part, it works again:

```
scala> (1 to 3).foreach(print(_ ))
123
```

I think the `(1 to 3).foreach(print(_ + ","))` might work because there is only one parameter, which is `_`. Why does scala complain about this?

Comment: Because it expands to `(1 to 3).foreach(print(x => x + ","))` which is illegal

Comment: @serejja Thanks! But why does `(1 to 3).foreach(print(_ ))` work? Won't it expand to `(1 to 3).foreach(print(x => x ))`, which is also illegal?

Comment: please see this answer  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1025181/hidden-features-of-scala/1083523#1083523 In short, `(1 to 3).foreach(print(_ + ","))` translates to the thing I wrote above, and `(1 to 3).foreach(print(_))` translates into `(1 to 3).foreach(x => print(x))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
(1 to 3).foreach(print(_ + ","))
```

expands to

```
(1 to 3).foreach(print(x => x + ","))
```

which is as invalid as the former.

On the other hand

```
 (1 to 3).foreach(print(_))
```

expands to

```
 (1 to 3).foreach(x => print(x))
```

which is perfectly legal.

In short, the `_` expands to an explicit lambda parameter, which is then used as argument in the body of the lamba.

Comment: Thanks! Is there any documents to describe the mechanism? I didn't find one by google..

Comment: google "scala lambda underscore" and you'll find plenty. This is a good one: http://www.codecommit.com/blog/scala/quick-explanation-of-scalas-syntax