# need clarity about use of single underscore only in scala

Tags: scala

not able to type underscore in question. The code snippet has underscore though.

why list.map(*+2) works in place of list.map(x=>x+2) but list.map(*) doesnt work in place of list.map(x=>x)?

```
scala> val list = List(1,2,3,4)
list: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4)

scala> list.map(_+2)
res14: List[Int] = List(3, 4, 5, 6)

scala> list.map(x=>x+2)
res15: List[Int] = List(3, 4, 5, 6)

scala> list.map(x=>x)
res16: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4)

scala> list.map(_)
<console>:13: error: missing parameter type for expanded function ((x$1) => list.map(x$1))
       list.map(_)
                ^

scala>
```

Comment: Underscores, in Scala, [can be confusing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8000903/what-are-all-the-uses-of-an-underscore-in-scala).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's pretty simple. If `_` was considered a valid expression for anonymous function and translated to `x => x`, then `_ * 2` would be translated to `(x => x) * 2`, which would make placeholders useless. Instead Scala is trying to find the first complete expression going "outwards" from `_`. In case of `list.map(_)` it's `list.map(_)`, so you have `x => list.map(x)`.

More interesting examples:

```
_ + (2 * _) //> x => x + (y => 2 * y)
_ + 2 * _   //> (x, y) => x + 2 * y
```

(parentheses "complete" expression)

Answer (score 2):

For this you need to use the `identity` function. That's because in this case, the placeholder `_` makes your expression `list.map(_)` a partially applied function. Maybe it makes it clearer if you assign it to a val:

```
val fun: (Int => Int) => List[Int] = list.map(_)
```

You could then use your `val fun` like so:

```
fun(_ * 2) // returns List(2, 4, 6, 8)
```

If you want to map to the same value, you can use `identity`:

```
list.map(identity) // returns List(1, 2, 3, 4)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `_` in what you're describing is [placeholder syntax for anonymous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1025181/hidden-features-of-scala/1083523#answer-1083523) functions and represents an argument to a function.

E.g:

```
list.map(_+2) // map takes a function which takes one argument and returns that arg + 2
```

Since map takes a function as an argument, and not a placeholder, that is why you're seeing this issue.