# Extending a Function1 in Scala

Tags: scala

In few examples, I have seen that an object or a class extends `Function1`.

E.g. `object Cash extends (CashProduct => String)` in [Hidden features of Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1025181/hidden-features-of-scala?answertab=oldest#tab-top)

(I suppose `A => B` means `Function1`)

What it the benefit of extending a `Function1`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The full example of what you provided:

```
object Cash extends (CashProduct => String) {
  def apply(p: CashProduct) = p.currency.name + "="

  def unapply(s: String)(implicit ps: ProductService): Option[CashProduct] = {
    if (s.endsWith("=") 
      Some(ps.findCash(s.substring(0,3))) 
    else None
  }
}
```

Shows that OP wanted to gain the syntactical benefit of the `apply` method, which allows your to create an instance calling `Cash(...)`.

But why would you really want to extend a function? Lets look at a better case perhaps, `List[T]`.

If we look up the long inheritance hierarchy, we'll see that:

```
trait Seq[+A] extends PartialFunction[Int, A]
```

Hmm, why does `Seq` extend `PartialFunction[Int, A]` (which in turns inherits `Function1[A, B]`? Because if we think about it, if I pass a List[A] an `Int`, representing *the index of the element I'm seeking*, it will (not efficiently) return me the element at that given index (if present).

Comment: I understood the explanation for `Seq`. Am I correct that in OP's example, there is no need to extend `CashProduct => String` because the OP is using `apply` to avoid using `new` keyword when creating `Cash` (similar to `val l = List(1,2,3)`. OP is not using the `apply` and `isDefinedAt` of `PartialFunctions` to do something like `Cash(cp)` to get  value (similar to `l(1)` which would return `2`)

Comment: @ManuChadha You're right. The same would work if OP would just supply `def apply` without extending function.

Answer (score 1):

The benefit of extending `Function1` as compared to just defining `apply` is just that you can pass this object where a `Function1` is expected. E.g.

```
val products: List[CashProduct] = ...
products.map(Cash)
```

Without the `extends` it would have to be written as

```
val products: List[CashProduct] = ...
products.map(Cash(_)) 
// or products.map(Cash.apply)
```

Comment: Is it not weird to extend function just for syntactical convince?

Comment: Not particularly? E.g. all case class companion objects do the same.