# Scala high order functions confusion

Tags: scala

In Scala there are high order functions, which from what I understand either function that return function or function that accept function.

this for example is high order function that takes function from Int to Int:

```
def highOrderFunc(f: Int => Int) = {
   ???
}
```

why when i call highOrderFunc with `List(1,2,3)` it compiles? from this signature I though I need to pass a function...im confused here, can someone explain this please?

Answer (score 3):

`List[A]` extends `Seq[A]` which also extends `PartialFunction[Int, A]`:

```
trait Seq[+A] extends PartialFunction[Int, A]
                      with Iterable[A]
                      with GenSeq[A]
                      with GenericTraversableTemplate[A, Seq]
                      with SeqLike[A, Seq[A]]
```

And `PartialFunction[Int, A]` extends `Function1[A, B]` or `(A => B)`. In your case `A` is `Int`, so `Int => Int` is a parent of `PartialFunction[Int, Int]` which is a parent of `Seq[Int]` which is a parent of `List[Int]`.

That's why you can pass `List[Int]` as `Function1[Int, Int]` or `Int => Int`

Comment: will have to be careful with that one then. Presumably this a conscious design decision on `Seq` rather than an undesired artefact of the collections hierarchy architecture?

Comment: According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47537784/9128490) it is probably made for convenience because of method `apply` when we get element by index like `someList(1)` or `someSeq(1)`

Comment: This is intended, and a useful feature. A list is just a mapping from index to value. Its apply method takes in the index, and returns a value. Syntactically, doThing(1) might be a list index or a function call, and there really shouldn't be any reason to care. In either case, we pass in an int and get something out.

Answer (score 2):

This works because a `List(1, 2, 3)` extends `Int => Int`. Somewhere up the class hierarchy, `List` extends `Function1` (the actual trait behind the `=>` syntax, which is just that, syntax). Try it, it'll be a partial function from index to elements.

```
@ val f : Int => Int = List(1, 2, 3) 
f: Int => Int = List(1, 2, 3)

@ f(2) 
res6: Int = 3

@ f(5) 
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: 5
  scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized.apply(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:63)
  scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized.apply$(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:61)
  scala.collection.immutable.List.apply(List.scala:86)
  scala.collection.immutable.List.apply(List.scala:86)
  scala.Function1.apply$mcII$sp(Function1.scala:36)
  scala.Function1.apply$mcII$sp$(Function1.scala:36)
  scala.collection.AbstractSeq.apply$mcII$sp(Seq.scala:41)
  ammonite.$sess.cmd7$.<init>(cmd7.sc:1)
  ammonite.$sess.cmd7$.<clinit>(cmd7.sc)
```